# Problems reading excel fila: "'utf-16-le' codec can't decode bytes in position 252-253: illegal UTF-16 surrogate"

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe, encoding

I am trying to open in Spyder-Python, the following document https://intranet2.sbs.gob.pe/estadistica/financiera/2019/Noviembre/C-1231-no2019.XLS

But when I put the following code:

```
database = pd.read_excel('C:\Users\hola\Downloads\C-1231-no2019.XLS')
```

suddenly appears the following error: "'utf-16-le' codec can't decode bytes in position 252-253: illegal UTF-16 surrogate". What can I do in order to fix through python code this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I opened it successfully. Which versions of PANDAS and XLRD are you using?

Comment: @gtomer I use the version '1.5.3', which version do you have?

Comment: Pandas version 2.0.0,